# How to get data from html form and save in database(with button) using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I want to get data from input boxes and save it in a database with a click on the button. I'm using angular. How can I get this data from my form? Please help me.
I have this HTML code:

```
<form ng-submit="createUser(userForm.$valid)" name="userForm1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="database_address">User</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="usernamee" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="passwordd"required id="password"   />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Operator</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="namee" required id="username"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createUser();" type="submit">Add user</button>
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Добавяне на нов</button>-->
</form>
```

And Angular code:

```
$scope.createUser=function()
{
    //console.log($scope.activeItem);
        //delete $scope.activeItem.hash_method
        var objectToSave = {
            username: console.log($scope.usernamee),
            password: console.log($scope.passwordd),
            name: console.log($scope.namee),
            id: $scope.id
        };
         {
            defaultAdapter.query('INSERT INTO users(username,password,name,id) VALUES(username = :usernamee, password = :passwordd,name = :namee WHERE id =:id)',
              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });

        }
}
```

Comment: According to me, you'll need an API along with the backend. See an example [here](https://www.formget.com/angularjs-crud/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form ng-submit="createUser(userForm)" name="userForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="database_address">User</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="user.usernamee" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="user.passwordd"required id="password"   />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Operator</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="user.namee" required id="username"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add user</button>
</form>
```

angularjs code

```
$scope.user={}//declare user object
$scope.createUser=function(userForm)
{
    console.log($scope.user);
    //for saving data in database, you'll need an API along with the backend.
}
```

Comment: Which API i have to use ?

Comment: I am talking about  RESTful api. Using angularjs $http service you can call restful web api.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking in my application is using "Sequelize" method. Is it possible this method to do this connection with database ?